# Regex parse video duration string

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all video duration links in comments and convert them to anchor tags.

The durations might look like:

```
01:20:55 (h:m:s)
20:30 (m:s)
1:21 (m:s)
1:35:12 (h:m:s)
```

I feel like I might be close but am pretty new to regex still

http://regexr.com/3bfmu

```
^([\d]{1,2}\:)?([\d]{1,2})?\:([\d]{1,2})$
```

to be used in this context:

```
$parsedTimeCommentString = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2}\:)?([\d]{1,2})?\:([\d]{1,2})$/", 
"<a href=\"#\" class=\"video-seek\" data-seek=\"$1:$2:$3\">$1:$2:$3</a>",
 $comment['comment']);
```

Comment: Are the durations all in one string? Take off the trailing anchor and should work for you. https://regex101.com/r/hS1zG2/1

Comment: Just updated my regex link to include use cases

Comment: Okay, and what is wrong with your current regex? All values are found, enable the `global` flag on that site to see it. `preg_replace` is global by default.

Comment: That was definitely where I was tripping up not enabling the global flag on that site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the anchors, and use a non-capturing group to disallow the colon:

```
(?:(\d{1,2}):)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vD7tP7/3)

Comment: I think I'd also just do `\d{2}` for seconds. I've never seen `m:s` formatted as `5:3` for `5:03`.

Answer (score 1):

It might look weird, but I think it should look more like this:

```
(?<![\d:])(?:(?:(\d\d?):([0-5]\d))|([0-5]?\d)):([0-5]\d)(?![\d:])
```

to keep format: hh:mm:ss, h:mm:ss, mm:ss, m:ss and avoid matching invalid (for time formatting) strings, like: 1:3:4, 14:1:14, 45:4:4, 88:99, 345:456 (as 45:45), 2:3, etc.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vD7tP7/4)

It captures hours in $1 and sec in $4, but minutes are captured in $2 or $3.

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the line anchors (^$) so that your string can match timestamps within other text. Also, you should make the second capture group non-optional, so that something like ':3' can't get through. And you'll want to make it global with /g so that it replaces all occurences. Something like this:

```
/([\d]{1,2}\:)?([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{1,2})/g
```